# Issue understanding a particular problem regarding homology of 3-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a closed connected 3-manifold, and write $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ as $\mathbb{Z^r} \oplus T$ where $T$ is torsion. Show that $H_2(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is $\mathbb{Z^r}$ if $M$ is orientable or $\mathbb{Z^{r-1}} \oplus \mathbb{Z_2}$ if $M$ is not orientable.

I tried applying the UCT for Homology but I am not getting any information about $H_2$. On the other hand, when I used UCT for cohomology I am unable to proceed because of the $Ext(*)$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you apply Poincare duality? $H^1(M)\cong H_2(M)$, and then you may apply UCT to $H^1(M)$ (for orientable case).

Comment: And for the non-orientable case, you might want to appeal to some betti number argument and the theorem that states that the torsion of $H_{n-1}$ for non-orientable closed connected manifold is $\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $H_2(M, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z^r}$ if $M$ is orientable, $\mathbb{Z^{r-1}} \oplus \mathbb{Z_2}$ if nonorientable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059557/show-h-2m-mathbbz-mathbbzr-if-m-is-orientable-mathbbzr-1)

Comment: Try using the fact that the Euler characteristic of an odd dimension manifold (closed and connected) is zero. In addition, if M is orientable you can tell what $H_3(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is, and if M is not orientable you can also tell what the torsion subgroup of $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is.